# Does Jinput has a limit of max file size that supersedes PHP directives?

Tags: joomla-4.x, development

Here's one that is driving me crazy:

- PHP memory_limit: 512M
- PHP post_max_size: 256M
- PHP upload_max_filesize: 128M

```
$app = Factory::getApplication();
dd($app->getInput()->files->get('jform'));
```

Returns:

- relevant data if upload a 32M .pdf file
- null if I upload a 62M .pdf file

Any tips on why is this happening?
Does

```
$app->getInput()->files
```

has any limit of max file size that supersedes PHP directives?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It could be because the file is detected as unsafe by file filter in Joomla. Unfortunately, the file filter is prone to false-positives which is most likely what's happening in your case. If you have your own way of ensuring safety of the file, you can bypass Joomla's filter by setting the filter argument to `RAW`:

```
$app->getInput()->files->get('jform', null, 'RAW')
```

Comment: Thanks so much @Sharky. That was indeed part of the problem.
The other one was the need for setting allow "unsafe" on File::upload($src, $dest, false, true);

Answer (score 2):

This is just one of Joomla frustrating:

**works ok for small files, returns null on large files:**

```
$app->getInput()->files->get('jform')
```

**works ok for both small and large files:**

```
$app->getInput()->files->getArray()['jform']
```

And just for clarification: it ALWAYS works if I use $_FILES instead for $app->getInput()